# Format if cell partially matches another

Tags: excel, match, partial, conditional-formatting, formulas

I have two columns with telephone numbers in them, I want cells `B2` and `B3` to change colour depending on whether they match the last 4 digits in the column next to them:

[image: SO20748315 question example]

`B2` turns green as it matches the end of `A2` and `B3` turns red as it does not match the last four digits of `A3`.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you just use one rule, say format all red and use the CF to change that to green only when there is a match, say with:

```
=B1=VALUE(RIGHT(A1,4))
```

in B1 and applied to B:B.